# Cannot run Apache2.4 with xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Till yesterday everything was fine with my Apache. But when I start it now get that errors :

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 520 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Syntax error on line 17 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf:
>   Cannot load C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.     .

Line 520 is: Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

Line 17 is : LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"

Someone? 
thanks

Comment: Did you check if `C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll` is there?

Comment: "could not be found" seems obvious enough...

Comment: Yeah I suddenly  change that folder to php1. Thank it works now !!

Comment: What did you do? Change that folder to php1. ? please elaborate for me to work with that too. I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

As the message is shown `"The specified module could not be found". It means the`php7ts.dll`module is missed or not exist`"C:/xampp/php/"` directory.

Please go to `"C:/xampp/php/"` directory and check the `php7ts.dll` module exists, If not then download from [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=29668). Get `php7ts.dll` module and in `"C:/xampp/php/"` directory. Restart the xampp server.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the php, make sure you can start it manually, by clicking on `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`.
If you can't start it manually and it shows you error in `vcruntime140.dll` Then you must install it
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685