# Window 10 pro XAMPP New Installation Cannot Start

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When i start apache server with bat, it show below error

and stop.

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 536 of C: /xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of C: /xampp/apache/conf/ extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load /xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: Access is denied.
```

this is what line 17 with syntax error on line 17 of httpd-xampp.conf
`LoadFile "c:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"`

original code
`LoadFile "/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"`

i try both also cannot work.

Comment: can you start xampp using the application?

Comment: Did you change any configuration in your xampp? Like php.ini, conf files, etc. Or is this a new installed xampp?

Comment: Do you have read access to `"c:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php7ts.dll cannot load into server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416939/php7ts-dll-cannot-load-into-server)

Comment: i try PHP 7 (php.exe -v to find out which one is installed) it show error as Access is denied.

Comment: is new installed xampp, even i try reinstall also same.

Comment: have read access to ```"c:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll``` just like normal window setting.

Comment: I guess you could improve your question, running inside the apache/bin folder the following DOS command: httpd -t. This command will reveal what is the error in line 536 of httpd.conf, which was not informed by you. By the way: there is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198686/xampp-apache-not-starting-php7ts-dll?rq=2 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834490/cannot-run-apache2-4-with-xampp?rq=2